# Как обработать fetch() = error 400 от сервера без перенаправления на авторизацию

Tags: vue.js, typescript, asp.net-core, авторизация, http-status-code-400

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему при получении ответа 400 от сервера на странице может происходить перенаправление на страницу авторизации вместо рендера пустой страницы?

Если учесть, что пользователь уже авторизован и ему не нужно дополнительно вводить свои данные для авторизации, нужно просто отобразить пустую страницу из store, как можно избежать такого перенаправления после вызова fetch к API?

Если закомментировать вызов safeFetch, то отображается нормальная пустая страница и перенаправления не происходит.

```
export const errors = {
    process: async (response: Response): Promise<FormattedResponse> => {
        let result = {} as FormattedResponse;
        switch (response.status) {
        //...
            case 400: result = { isSuccess: false, result: {}, isAuthorized: undefined, isIdentified: undefined }
        //...
        }
        return result;
    }
}
async function safeFetch(url: string): Promise<FormattedResponse> {
    const resp = await fetch(url, { credentials: 'include', headers: headers });

    return await errors.process(resp);
};
export async function getPagedApiResponse(url: string, argument: string, id: string = null): Promise<VueTemplateState> {

    let state = store.state.vuePageTemplate;
    //комментируем safeFetch и перенаправления не происходит 
    //но как тогда получить данные с API?
    const resp = await safeFetch(url + argument + '&' + id); // https://my.api/items-paged?pageNumber=0&itemId=4

    const stateKey = Object.keys(ENDPOINTS).find(k => ENDPOINTS[k] === url); 
    state[stateKey] = resp.result;
    state.isAuthorized = resp.isAuthorized;
    state.isIdentified = resp.isIdentified;
        
    return state;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В общем пришлось поправить API, чтобы оно не возвращало ошибку 400 при неверных аргументах, а просто пустой объект JSON. Всё-равно API контроллер работает только для авторизованных пользователей.

Скорее всего ошибка связана с конфигурацией всего ASP.CORE сайта, т.к. весь vue вызывается из-под razor pages.